# Modifying an opened temporary file from another process in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to launch an editor from a Ruby script to edit an existing string and then retrieve the modified contents when the editor exits:

```
require 'tempfile'

STARTING_TEXT = <<~STR
Blah blah blah
blah balh blah
STR

Tempfile.create do |f|
  f.write(STARTING_TEXT)
  f.flush()
  f.rewind()
  system( "vim #{f.path}" )
  puts f.read
end
```

The problem is that, regardless of what I put in the temp file in the editor, `f.read` always and only returns the `STARTING_TEXT`. I know that I am successfully writing the file from the editor because, if I pause execution after the `system()` call with a breakpoint, I can `cat` the tempfile and see the modified contents.

It seems like some kind of buffering, either Ruby or OS-based, is preventing me from getting the modified text file contents. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with:

```
Tempfile.create('.') do |f|
  f.write STARTING_TEXT
  f.flush
  system( "vim #{f.path}" )
  puts f.read
end
```

Looks like `f.rewind` is your problem.  BTW parenthesis on ruby method calls are optional. Surely not needed if you're not passing any arguments.

I ran this in MacOS 10.11.6 with rvm ruby-2.4.1 see my terminal output:

```
sandbox % ruby junk.rb
Blah blah bla
blah balh blah

These blahs ^^ where here already.
I typed this line in vim and then did :wq
sandbox %
```

Maybe try this to see if everything looks as you'd expect:

```
require 'tempfile'

STARTING_TEXT = <<~STR
Blah blah blah
blah balh blah
STR

def puts_info(f)
  puts f.path
  puts f.stat.to_s
end

Tempfile.create do |f|
  f.write(STARTING_TEXT)
  puts_info(f)
  f.flush
  f.rewind
  system( "vim #{f.path}" )
  puts f.read
  puts_info(f)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. As can be seen from the Ruby 2.5 docs, the `Tempfile#create` `basename` argument is optional. Also, I tried your solution and it does not work on my machine-- without `f.rewind` I get no output at all from `f.read` (which is what I would expect, since the `Tempfile` `pos` is past the point of the `STARTING_TEXT`). I'm not sure how you're getting this to work without rewind -- maybe it has something to do with OS differences? I'm on a Mac running High Sierra.

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.11.6 because I don't wanna "you must be f**kin' high Sierra" lol. Forced 2fac auth? no thanks. I tested this on 2.3.6 but let me test others and get back to you.

Comment: @SeanMackesey see my updated answer.  I even tried this doing `:q!` in vim and still got the output I typed in vim. As a 2nd test I tested this on a dockerized linux with ruby 2.3.6 and it also worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe one should `f.rewind` *after* the file was actually modified and *immediately before* `f.read`. The following works perfectly for me:

```
Tempfile.create(?.) do |f|
  f.write "Blah"
  f.flush
  system( "vim #{f.path}" )  # typing YAY
  f.rewind                   # ⇐ HERE!
  puts f.read
end    
#⇒ Blah
#  YAY
```

*Sidenote:* consider trying `$EDITOR` before `vim` hardcoded; the tastes of your users might differ :)